# How to compare two same name files in different directories using meld (without giving their path)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, compare, utility

I know commands:

1. To find path of file:

   ```
   find . -name filename
   ```
2. To compare two files:

   ```
   meld path_of_file_in_one_dir path_of_file_in_second_dir
   ```

I have to compare so many files in different sub directories of a directory, every time I have to first search the path of that file and then use this path with `meld`, and this I have to for each file.

It would be very easy if i only give names and root directory of that files to `meld`.

How can I combine `meld` and `find` commands so that I can apply it on each file?

Answer (score 0):

1. If your directory structure is like this say

   - test_folder

     - test1

       - file_to_cmp
     - test2

       - file_to_cmp
     - test3

       - file_to_cmp

then you can run the following

`meld find . -name "file*"` or 
       `meld find . -name "file_to_cmp"` 
This will compare the 3 files for sure. 
About more than three file comparing, I doubt meld can do it.